# Display Entire month(off's and the Active days)

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table that has the attendance of employee. The table records the Actions( present, Absent,late etc ) of an employee. The table only is used when the user is present. There is no entry on off days(weekends). I want to display all the month including the days he was absent and the weekends.
for eg: If a person comes for 20 days, it should display all the 30 days including the days he was present. I have tried GetDate but that works for attendance for the individual date.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Calendar` table.  This should contain every date you'll ever need with flags to say if that date is a weekday, weekend, bank-holiday, etc.

Then it's simply a LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Calendar
LEFT JOIN
  yourTable
    ON  yourTable.date = Calendar.date
    AND yourTable.user = 12345
WHERE
      Calendar.date >= '2014-02-01'
  AND Calendar.date <  '2014-03-01'
```

For multiple users, join the `calendar` table to the `user` table first.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Calendar
CROSS JOIN
  User
LEFT JOIN
  yourTable
    ON  yourTable.date = Calendar.date
    AND yourTable.user = User.id
WHERE
      Calendar.date >= '2014-02-01'
  AND Calendar.date <  '2014-03-01'
  AND User.id       IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

This pattern essentially treats dates as a dimension (the Calendar table), which you combine with other dimension tables to make a template for your data.  Then you `LEFT JOIN` your fact table on to your dimensional template.